# Hibernate query for following scenario

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I created a class as follows...

```
public class BeanA{
  private String customerId;
  private String cutomerName;
  private Map<String, SubMarket> subMarkets = new HashMap<>();

   public String getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
   }

   public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
   }

   public String getCutomerName() {
    return cutomerName;
   }

   public void setCutomerName(String cutomerName) {
    this.cutomerName = cutomerName;
   }

   public Map<String, String> getSubMarkets() {
    return subMarkets;
   }

   public void setSubMarkets(Map<String, String> subMarkets) {
    this.subMarkets = subMarkets;
   }
}
```

And I did the hibernate mapping too.

It is totally working.

Now I want to get result set where [Map] key=some value and value= some value...

I am hoping a hibernate query to get that result set.

Comment: I got the correct answer finally by my self: 
from [tableName]C where 'test' in indices(C.[mapName]) and 'Success' in elements(C.[mapName])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the correct answer finally by my self:

```
 from [tableName]C where 'test' in indices(C.[mapName]) and 'Success' in elements(C.[mapName])
```

Answer (score 0):

JPQL query is as follows

```
SELECT a FROM BeanA a JOIN a.subMarkets s 
WHERE KEY(s) = :some AND VALUE(s) = : someOther
```

assuming that Hibernate version is one with [HHH-5396](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5396) fixed.

Comment: My hibernate version not supported for this

Answer (score 0):

You can load your data as a map like this:

Hibernate doc example:

```
select 
    new map(
        max(bodyWeight) as max,
        min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n 
    ) 
from Cat cat
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select

Comment: I want to search not to load